# Android ImageView убрать оттенок цвета

Tags: android, kotlin

Первоначально для ImageView установлена картинка и оттенок цвета

```
<ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_online_check"
                            android:layout_width="90dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp""
                            app:tint="@color/loginTextHint"
                          app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_arrow_forward_ios_white_48"/>
```

Затем из кода мне нужно заменить картинку

```
ivOnlineCheckError.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_error_outline_24)
```

Но оттенок остался, как можно его убрать?

Comment: для изменения оттенка программно используйте `setColorFilter`

Comment: @McDaggen мне не нужно его изменять, мне нужно его удалить

Comment: `ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(iv_online_check, null)`